# Deploy .NET Core app to Linux giving me Site Cannot be Reached

Tags: linux, angular, asp.net-core

Created a default .NET Core Web Application with Angular (literally created through Visual Studio 2019 and then published through Visual Studio 2019 with the Linux x64 profile). I copied the entire publish directory to a directory on my linux machine and ran the application. The application starts and says browse to http://localhost:5000. Well this linux machine only has shell access. So from my Windows machine (which can access other web applications on this machine from a different port) I open up the website (assume name of linux server is called 'linuxsvr') http://linuxsvr:5000 in Chrome Browser and I get this site cannot be reached.

I deployed using Self Contained Deployment so I'm not reliant on .NET Core being on the Linux machine. I'm apparently missing something. What is the correct way to deploy to a Linux Machine (specifically Ubuntu Server 14.04) with Self Contained Deployment?

Comment: You missed that fact that what is localhost. To allow Kestrel to handle requests other than localhost, simply ask it to bind to something else https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2#endpoint-configuration Usually `--urls http://0.0.0.0:5000` is enough.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks that actually worked! I can probably set that up in a .json file though right? According to this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2#override-configuration

It goes in `hostsettings.json` which I apparently don't have. Can the setting go into a different json file and if so what would be the format to define it?